# where did the pma__ tables come from when I migrated to new server

Tags: php, mysql

A few months ago, I migrated a PHP application to a new pi. I moved all the scripts and dumped the tables using phpmyadmin export. I then imported the tables in the new server. There were a few problems with permissions and the like, but I got everything working. The only thing is, there are a bunch of new tables that appeared like pma__bookmark, pma__central_columns, pma__column_info.

Only five of these tables have any rows;
pma__expoprt_templates (1 row),
pma__favorite (1 row),
pma__recent (2 rows),
pma__table_uiprefs (4 rows),
pma__userconfig (2 rows).

Can anyone tell me where these tables came from and is it safe to remove them?
Did I inadvertently install some app while I was building this lamp server?

Comment: my guess is that pma comes from phpMyAdmin .... why don't you search linux sites? ... your question is not about Raspberry Pi